# MySQL Update or Insert depending on NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, async-await

I've got a table which holds 3 tags per `audioid`. These are columns named `tagid1`, `tagid2` and `tagid3`. The default value of these in the database is NULL.

I'd like to check whether a row exists with tagid1. If it exists or is NULL I need to update the column. But if the row doesn't exist at all I need to insert a brand new row. Here's what I've tried which results in a duplicate inserted row instead of an updated row;

```
row_c = await db.query("SELECT tagid1 FROM entitytag WHERE audioid = ?", [audioid]);

if (row_c.length > 0) { 

    var etid1 = row_c[0].etid; 

    row_d = await db.query("UPDATE entitytag SET tagid1 = ? WHERE etid =?", [tagid1, etid1]);   

} else {

    row_e = await db.query("INSERT INTO entitytag  (audioid, tagid1, userid)  VALUES (?,?,?)", [audioid, tagid1, userid ]);     
}
```

Comment: Use `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is sometimes referred as INSERT/UPDATE. Please check the link below for mysql tutorial. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/